# Auto Generated number in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

I JS code that generate 15 digit number in a text box and I want to reduce the number generated to 5 or 6 digits. Please help me.

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        now = new Date();
        randomNum = '';
        randomNum += Math.round(Math.random() * 9);
        randomNum += Math.round(Math.random() * 9);
        randomNum += now.getTime();
        window.onload = function () {
            document.getElementById("txt_usrid").value = randomNum;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input type="text" tooltip="User Id" id="txt_usrid"/>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check this link [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gkzqqt6t/3/). hope it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `Array#slice`

```js
now = new Date();
randomNum = '';
randomNum += Math.round(Math.random() * 9);
randomNum += Math.round(Math.random() * 9);
randomNum += now.getTime().toString().slice(-4);

window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("txt_usrid").value = randomNum;
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
    <input type="text" tooltip="User Id" id="txt_usrid" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: 1. OP wants a 5 digit number, not 6. 2. The issue with this is that the last three digits will hardly change as they relate to the current year.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan see there *`I want to reduce the number generated to 5 or 6`* .OP wants `5 r 6`

Answer (score 0):

You could substring it with `substr`

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        now = new Date();
        randomNum = '';
        randomNum += Math.round(Math.random() * 9);
        randomNum += Math.round(Math.random() * 9);
        randomNum += now.getTime();
        window.onload = function () {
            document.getElementById("txt_usrid").value = randomNum.substr(0,5); // HERE ;)
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input type="text" tooltip="User Id" id="txt_usrid"/>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The issue with this is that the last three digits will hardly change as they relate to the current year.

Answer (score 0):

The most effective way to do this would be to retrieve the last 3 digits from `.getTime()` and append them to the 2 random integers. As these digits relate to the milliseconds of the current date they should mean the generated number has the appearance of being randomised - although obviously not truly random. Try this:

```js
now = new Date();
randomNum = '';
randomNum += Math.round(Math.random() * 9);
randomNum += Math.round(Math.random() * 9);
randomNum += now.getTime().toString().slice(-3);
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("txt_usrid").value = randomNum;
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
    <input type="text" tooltip="User Id" id="txt_usrid" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Rory McCrossan. It was great Help

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        now = new Date();
        randomNum = '';
        randomNum += Math.round(Math.random() * 9);
        randomNum += Math.round(Math.random() * 9);
        randomNum += Math.round(now.getTime() / 1000000000); // it was creating the number of milliseconds since 1970/01/01 so it should be less
        randomNum = Math.round(Math.random() * randomNum);
        window.onload = function () {
            document.getElementById("txt_usrid").value = randomNum;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input type="text" tooltip="User Id" id="txt_usrid"/>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Updated** : generate more random numbers

Comment: The issue with this is that the last three digits will hardly change as they relate to the current year.

Comment: Add this line `randomNum = Math.round(Math.random() * randomNum);` @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 0):

```js
now = new Date();
randomNum = '';
randomNum += Math.round(Math.random() * 9);
randomNum += Math.round(Math.random() * 9);
randomNum += now.getTime().toString().slice(-3);
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("txt_usrid").value = randomNum;
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
    <input type="text" tooltip="User Id" id="txt_usrid" />
  </div>
</form>
```

```js
now = new Date();
randomNum = '';
randomNum += Math.round(Math.random() * 9);
randomNum += Math.round(Math.random() * 9);
randomNum += now.getTime().toString().slice(-3);
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("txt_usrid").value = randomNum;
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
    <input type="text" tooltip="User Id" id="txt_usrid" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try [String.substring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) Method :**

```js
now = new Date();
randomNum = '';
randomNum += Math.round(Math.random() * 9);
randomNum += Math.round(Math.random() * 9);
randomNum += now.getTime();
console.log(randomNum.substring(5, 11));
```